# Send reply with pre-prepared answers

Tags: plugins, customization, comments

Do you know the way to ask users' comments with pre-prepared answers? 
What i want is very simple and more like  a comments section that only can select and remove emojis without typing and have 4 elements:

1. A text box that user type her/his name in it (it doesn't require registration)
2. A text box that user can't type anything, Just can select what they want and preview selected items in the text box and can remove them (Just like stackexchange Tags but without Typing)
3. A submit button that Send selected items and the user's name to the Comments section (its something like chat windows but its more than like a forum)
4. The comments section that show users names and they selected items

if you know plugins for it (its not important premium or free) or codes that help me please ,,, 
[image: I prepared an image of what I think.]